# как написать код короче на С++11 с помощью variadic template

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++11

кто знает,подскажите плиз как переписать вот такой код через пакеты расширений variadic template(template<class...Ts> struct MakeTypelist{};?

```
template <int POSITION,class TPin>
struct PW {
  typedef TPin    Pin;
  enum {position = POSITION};
};
//---------------------------------------------------

    template
<
  int Position, // стартовая битовая позиция, сначала это 0
  typename T1 = NullType, typename T2 = NullType, typename T3 = NullType,
  typename T4 = NullType, typename T5 = NullType, typename T6 = NullType,
  typename T7 = NullType, typename T8 = NullType, typename T9 = NullType,
  typename T10 = NullType, typename T11 = NullType, typename T12 = NullType,
  typename T13 = NullType, typename T14 = NullType, typename T15 = NullType,
  typename T16 = NullType, typename T17 = NullType
>
struct MakePinList
{
private:
  // рекурсивно проходим все параметры
  // на следующей итерации Position увеличится на 1,
  // а T2 превратится в T1 и так далее
  typedef typename MakePinList
    <
    Position + 1,
    T2, T3, T4,
    T5, T6, T7,
    T8, T9, T10,
    T11, T12, T13,
    T14, T15, T16,
    T17
    >::Result TailResult;
  enum { PositionInList = Position };
public:
  // Result это и есть требуемый список линий
  typedef Typelist< PW<T1, PositionInList>, TailResult> Result;
};

//конец списка
    //конец рекурсии, когда список пуст 
template<int Position>
struct MakePinList<Position>
{
  typedef NullType Result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно, вам нужен именно С++11, или "С++11 или новее". На C++14 выглядит так:

```
template <typename ...P>
struct TypeList {};

template <int I, typename T>
struct PW
{
    using Pin = T;
    static constexpr int position = I;
};

namespace detail
{
    template <typename I, typename ...P>
    struct MakePinList {};
    
    template <int ...I, typename ...P>
    struct MakePinList<std::integer_sequence<int, I...>, P...>
    {
        using type = TypeList<PW<I, P>...>;
    };
}

template <typename ...P>
using PinList = typename detail::MakePinList<std::make_integer_sequence<int, sizeof...(P)>, P...>::type;
```

`PinList<int, float, double>` -> `TypeList<PW<0, int>, PW<1, float>, PW<2, double>`.

Comment: Да. спасибоооо!!! Я микроконтроллеры в Atmel Studio  драйвера пишу. А там С++11 стандарт компилятор поддерживает только .. попробую Ваш код сейчас.

Comment: @drew Версию компилятора заодно скажите.

Comment: обновил atmelStudio до 7.0 .компилятор avr-gcc++ 7.2. удалось запустить даже на С++17. Только вот как бы еще STL библиотеку прикрутить туда? а то например он std::integer_sequence не понимает...

Comment: @drew А `#include <utility>` написали?

Comment: Написал, но -    Error utility:    No such file or directory

Comment: @drew Ууу. Можно пойти поискать готовую реализацию `integer_sequence`, или утащить ее из обычного `g++` 7.2 (не AVR). Можно переписать без `integer_sequence`, но это чуть более муторно.

Comment: Вот эта интересная мысль утащить готовую реализацию из g++. ну как ее к avr прикрутить? конечно обидно изобретать свой велосипед когда есть готовые библиотеки..  хотя может и зря я с С++ все это затеял, но все-таки очень заманчиво на С++ шаблонах можно реализацию виртуальных портов замастырить - создать одну структуру и  таскать эту библиотеку можно в любой микроконтроллер. без всяких define .просто в MakePinList подставляешь нужные порты и все... причем даже в дизассемблере все выглядит красиво,ни одной лишней команды на асме..

Answer (score 0):

вот моя реализация integer_sequence :

```
template <int... Ns>
struct sequence {};


template <int... Ns>
struct seq_gen;

template <int I, int... Ns>
struct seq_gen<I, Ns...> {
  using type = typename seq_gen<I - 1, I - 1, Ns...>::type;
};


template <int... Ns>
struct seq_gen<0, Ns...> {
  using type = sequence<Ns...>;
};

template <int N>
using sequence_t = typename seq_gen<N>::type;

//======================================================================

template <typename ...P>
struct TypeList {};

template <int I, typename T>
struct PW
{
  using Pin = T;
  static constexpr int position = I;
};

namespace detail
{
  template <typename I, typename ...P>
  struct MakePinList {};

  template <int ...I, typename ...P>
  struct MakePinList<sequence_t< I...>, P...>
  {
    using type = TypeList<PW<I, P>...>;
  };
}

template <typename ...P>
using PinList = typename detail::MakePinList<sequence_t< sizeof...(P)>, P...>::type;
```

но чего-то не хватает, компилятор пишет:

Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  C2210   "N": расширения пакетов невозможно использовать в качестве аргументов для неупакованных параметров в шаблонах псевдонимов   MakePinList F:\QTproj\MakePinList\MakePinList.cpp   43
Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка (активно)    E0842   constant "I" не используется или не может быть выведено из списка аргументов шаблона шаблон класса "detail::MakePinList<sequence_t<I...>, P...>"    MakePinList F:\QTproj\MakePinList\MakePinList.cpp   42
Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  C3855   detail::MakePinList: параметр шаблон "I" несовместим с объявлением  MakePinList F:\QTproj\MakePinList\MakePinList.cpp   46